# How to combine these two routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes, laravel-5

I have these two routes:

```
Route::post('/post',
    array(
        'uses' => 'PostController@newPost'
    )
);

Route::post('/post/picture',
    array(
        'uses' => 'PostController@newPost'
    )
);
```

In the actual controller, I differentiate between the two parameters (since they use the same controller), but how can I combine the two routes above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the following a try

```
Route::post('/post/{picture?}',
    array(
        'uses' => 'PostController@newPost'
    )
);
```

Wrapping `picture` in the `{}` brackets treats that URL segment as a parameter.  Using a `?` at the end of the parameter treats it as optional.  One caveat: This will also catch things like

```
/post/some-other-thing
```

If you're concerned about catching the other items, give the following a try

```
Route::post('/post/{myvar?}',
    array(
        'uses' => 'PostController@newPost'
    )
)->where('myvar','picture');;
```

The second parameter to the `where` method can be any PCRE regular expression.

Comment: What if `picture` needs to be exactly the word `picture`? Your route allows anything in the url, like `/post/hey` or `/post/hello`. I need exactly only `/post/picture`.

Comment: Your updated route has no link to the controller though.